# Index (type) for searching (large) unsorted array

Tags: csv, delphi, tdictionary

I have program that loads a (sometimes) large CSV file into an array. The data cannot be sorted, and I do not know if the data is text or numbers. This is up to customers.

Example could be

```
1;JOHN;DOE
2;JANE;DOE;
3;BOBBY;NOTABLES
```

but it could also be strings

```
MB9384HJ;TEST1
B9284918;TEST2
```

The number of lines could be up to a few million.

I would like to seach for a specific value in a column (which one is known ahead of time, this is my "key index column"). Assume this is unique. Key is to find which row this column is in.

Currently the code is traversing from 1..n and comparing. This is obviously slower towards the end.

I am considering these options:

- a memory SQLite database with key index value and record number
- a TStringDictionary with key, record as the pairs
- a Hashed stringlist

My idea is: instead of traversing the array, I query the index for the key (client provides item to search for, it must be random-access). Then I immediately get the rownumber of the array, and I can fetch the data.

Which of the these (or other, if any) would be a better path to follow ?

Comment: I would use a `TDictionary` (which is actually a hash table) to map the key to the record number. Don't forget to pass a suitable capacity to the [constructor](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/System.Generics.Collections.TDictionary.Create) to avoid rehashing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQLite is probably too much if you just want to search for the key. It would be interesting if you fill a SQLite table with the CSV and have to do complex queries not only on the keys but also the other columns.

A Hashed string list is probably the faster but there is a problem with hash collisions.

A Dictionary is probably the best solution in your specific case. And it is easy since Delphi RTL provide the required generic class.

Comment: Tried with TIntegerDictionary from "Delphi Fundamentals 5.00", as my delphi version is before D2009.  Adding 750.000 records to the dictionary is < 1 second. Search results: Array search 1000x : 30-40 seconds.  Dictionary search : 100.000x : <  1 sec.

Answer (score 1):

Although the newer Delphi (2009+) has built in TDictionary, here (one possible) solution for older Delphi versions.

This is using [Delphi Fundamentals 5](https://github.com/fundamentalslib/fundamentals5https://github.com/fundamentalslib/fundamentals5) which can be compiled even for D6.

```pascal
uses 
   flcDataStructs;
//...
var
   thedict : TIntegerDictionary;
   i : integer;

begin
  thedict := TIntegerDictionary.Create;
  thedicnr.DuplicatesAction := ddIgnore;  // should there be duplicates in my key column

  for i := 0 to length(dataarray)-1 do
    begin
      thedict.Add(dataarray[i], i);
    end;
end;

// to use:
//    rownumber := thedict['stringToSearch'];
```